# Printing Array at a specific position / location java netbeans

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently learning Java in Netbeans and I am attempting an assignment given to me, which is on arrays and I am having difficulties on part 2 of the question which I am required to print numbers at a specific location.

Part 1 requires me to create and print an array of size 20 to insert random numbers between 1 to 7. Which I have completed.

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] myArray = new int[20];

    System.out.print("Array: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++)
   {
        int random = rand.nextInt(7) + 1;
        myArray[i] = random;           
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
   }
```

While part 2 now requires me to generate a random number between 0 to 19 which represents the array locations in part 1 and the program will have to print the 4 random numbers from that array location onwards while taking onto account on the array boundaries.

As right now I am currently stuck after generating random numbers from 0 to 19 and do not know what I should do to make the array print the 4 consecutive number after random2 location when random2 location is generated

```
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    int random2 = rand2.nextInt(19) + 1;
```

Comment: 4 consecutive ? what if 2nd random is 18? and also you are learning `java` not `javascript`

Comment: Oh i see sorry for the trouble I've caused and thanks for editing for me. And when the 2nd random is 18, the program will print the 4 consecutive location in front of it which is position 19, 20 , 1 , 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) generates random numbers between 0 to n-1 where n is passed as the argument to nextInt. So, for your purpose, you should use the following statement (You need not create another object of Random class, you can use the same object created previously)

```
int random2 = rand.nextInt(20);
```

since the array indices will be between 0 to 19. Next, you can print the 4 consecutive numbers in the array using the following loop:

```
for(int i = random2; i < random2 + 4; i++) {
    if(i < myArray.length) System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    else break;
}
```

Here, we check that if the index `i` we use in the loop exceeds array boundaries, then we break out of the printing loop. You may change the loop as per your requirement if printing 4 numbers is a hard requirement. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, took my quite a while to understand and I finally managed to grasp your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could for example proceed like this:

```
int count = 0;
while(count < 4 && (random2 + count) < myArray.length){
System.out.println(myArray[random2 + count - 1]);
count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help as well! Sorry for all the trouble I've caused as I'm still learning Java. I have managed to understand your method as well. Thank you so much!